# Css cheat sheet template

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a template for a cheat sheet in html, take as an example this [latex format](https://wch.github.io/latexsheet/).
The idea is to create 3 columns of height x and y row. The content has to follow this rule automatically.

This is what I've achieved so far, I'm albe to span the content automatically in multiple columns. The idea is that after the third column the rest of the content go to a new line and start another 3 column of the same height, and so on.

```css
.box {
  column-count: 3;
  column-rule: 2px solid black;
  column-fill: auto;
  height: 100px
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div> 1 </div>
  <div> 2 </div>
  <div> 3 </div>
  <div> 4 </div>
  <div> 5 </div>
  <div> 6 </div>
  <div> 7 </div>
  <div> 8 </div>
  <div> 9 </div>
  <div> 10 </div>
  <div> 11 </div>
  <div> 12 </div>
  <div> 13 </div>
  <div> 14 </div>
  <div> 15 </div>
  <div> 16 </div>
  <div> 17 </div>
  <div> 18 </div>
  <div> 19 </div>
  <div> 20 </div>
</div>
```

Someone has any idea?

Comment: Does this answers your question? [The Trickery it Takes to Create eBook-Like Text Columns](https://css-tricks.com/the-trickery-it-takes-to-create-ebook-like-text-columns/)

Comment: @Justinas not really, take a look at the latex example in the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, for who is instrested I'v used the following approch.

1. Create an array with all the divs
2. Render the table, get the element that are inside and remove them from the array.
3. Render the next table with the rest of the array, and so on.

Result:
[image: First Page]
[image: Second Page]
[image: Third Page]

Comment: If you add all relevant code, this could be a useful answer...

Comment: I'll create a github repo, since it's done with nextjs.

Answer (score 1):

An approximation using CSS grid:

```css
.box {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}
.box :nth-child(15n + 5) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.box :nth-child(15n + 1),
.box :nth-child(15n + 2),
.box :nth-child(15n + 3),
.box :nth-child(15n + 4),
.box :nth-child(15n + 5){
  grid-column:1;
}
.box :nth-child(15n + 6),
.box :nth-child(15n + 7),
.box :nth-child(15n + 8),
.box :nth-child(15n + 9),
.box :nth-child(15n + 10){
  grid-column:2;
}
.box :nth-child(15n + 11),
.box :nth-child(15n + 12),
.box :nth-child(15n + 13),
.box :nth-child(15n + 14),
.box :nth-child(15n + 15){
  grid-column:3;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div> 1 </div>
  <div> 2 </div>
  <div> 3 </div>
  <div> 4 </div>
  <div> 5 </div>
  <div> 6 </div>
  <div> 7 </div>
  <div> 8 </div>
  <div> 9 </div>
  <div> 10 </div>
  <div> 11 </div>
  <div> 12 </div>
  <div> 13 </div>
  <div> 14 </div>
  <div> 15 </div>
  <div> 16 </div>
  <div> 17 </div>
  <div> 18 </div>
  <div> 19 </div>
  <div> 20 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: nice solution but you are using a fixed number of elements per row or per column instead of relying on automatic flow based on the fixed height of the macro-row. I commented because I tried before when I read the question but couldn't get anywhere with css only

Comment: @DiegoDeVita that's why I said "approximation"

Comment: @Temani Afif super fancy, i would never have thought about that, but Diego it's right, it's not exactly what I was looking for. However I'm wondering at this point if it's possible to do with css only. I could add a script that get each element height and set them in the correct nth-child selector. So maybe 3 in the first line,  4 in the second and so on.
However I'll wait a bit to see if there is a easier solution with css only
Thanks!